# Casting primitive data types

Tags: java, casting, primitive-types

```
public class TestEmployee {
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
          byte b=(byte)1*200;
          System.out.println(b);
       }
   }
```

I have written above simple code. But I am getting folowing error "Possible loss of precision"

As of my knowledge, when we perform integer calculations , the operands are converted to int and then the calculation in performed. And final result is in int. Now as the range of byte data type is (-128 to 127) the above calculations falls out of range of byte. So I downcast it to byte. Then why I am getting the error.

Please help and correct my concepts of casting..

Answer (score 4):

You are casting the `1` to a byte, not the result of `1*200`. So you want to use

```
byte b = (byte)(1*200);
```

in this case.

Comment: Please can you help me in understanding the concept of Casting. I am very confused with  that.

Answer (score 1):

your code should go like this....just missing the brackets before the multiplication operation otherwise only 1 will be downcast and 200 remains as integer

```
public class TestEmployee {
public static void main(String args[]) 
{ byte b=(byte) ( 1 * 200); 
  System.out.println(b);
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the parenthesis `()` while downcasting.
Change like this,

```
   byte b=(byte)(1*200);
```

When you write like this,

```
   byte b=(byte)1*200;
                 ^
   `compilation error :  possible loss of precision`
```

It is because it tries to convert an `int : 200` to byte which will *result in compilation error*.

Comment: Please can you help me in understanding the concept of Casting. I am very confused with that.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't put `1 * 200` in brackets. It should be `byte b = (byte)(1 * 200).`

Otherwise you do `byte b = 200` which is an int and you get an error.